# Por que o modo subjuntivo tem apenas três tempos verbais?

Tags: verbos, modo-subjuntivo

Por que o modo subjuntivo tem apenas três tempos verbais: presente, pretérito imperfeito e futuro?

Comment: Na verdade há também no subjuntivo o **pretérito perfeito**, o **pretérito mais-que-perfeito** e o **futuro composto** (por exemplo, respectivamente: *tenha feito*, *tivesse feito* e *tiver feito*.)

Comment: Cheira-me que isto já venha do latim. Vamos ver se os latinistas aqui do site sabem.

Comment: Parece-me ampla demais a pergunta. A existência de três modos subjuntivos transcende a língua-pt para a própria linguística, passando por história e porventura filosofia.

Comment: Vou encerrar a questão e vou pesquisar melhor. Fiz a pergunta porque nos é ensinado que o modo indicativo tem seis tempos verbais e o modo subjuntivo tem três modos verbais como explicado a cima.

Comment: Responder "por que" é impossível, como os outros dizem, mas aqui há explicação do que ocorreu (não "por que"): <https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Portuguese_verbs> (seção Origin). Em suma, no latim havia quatro subjuntivos ativos (todos os tempos+aspectos menos os dois futuros), depois um deles se tornou o infinitivo pessoal, outros dois mudaram de significado, e então agora existem três subjuntivos.